# Is there a blockchain reddit alternative?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, bitcoin

Is there a blockchain Reddit alternative? I know of Reddit alternatives like [communities.win](https://communities.win/) but it's not blockchain and one cannot create a new community on one's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard about [Steemit](https://steemit.com) that's supposed to be like Reddit and what's awesome there is that anyone can earn their coin STEEM by just posting, commenting or upvoting. -> [Steemit-Newcomer-Guide](https://steemit.com/guide/@steemitblog/steemit-a-guide-for-newcomers)

There are also lots of other blockchain based social media platforms maybe there is one on this [list](https://www.leewayhertz.com/blockchain-social-media-platforms/) that you like.

Comment: Steemit is more of a decentralized Medium. Thanks for the list.

Comment: Edit: I looked at the list, did not find anything. Maybe because it does not exist? I accepted your answer for this reason

Comment: Could be the reason... maybe you should start developing a 'Blockchain Reddit' after your expectations :D

Comment: Im working on something else. (Not crypto-related). Perhaps in the near future if I have the time, and I feel it would make a strong contribution to opening up the flow of ideas. Anyone reading this could though... I think someone should.